# Undefined is not a function in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I get the error "undefined is not a function" when running this code locally and from a Dropbox public url, http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6862628/backbone.html.

However, when I run it on jsfiddle it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/fdKKD/

In short, I'm creating a simple model and a simple view. When I set a property on the model, the view console.log's "render".

I'm seeing the same behavior in Chrome 17 and Safari, Mac.

This is driving me nuts. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone requires either jQuery or Zepto to be loaded *before* Backbone if you intend to do any DOM manipulation (i.e. if you use a view). Your HTML includes things in this order:

1. Underscore.
2. Backbone.
3. jQuery.

So Backbone doesn't know if it should use jQuery or Zepto when it loads and you end up with an undefined value being used a function. Your original jsfiddle uses jQuery in the sidebar so jQuery will be loaded by jsfiddle *before* your `<script>` tags are hit, so Backbone sees jQuery, uses it, and everything works. If you switch to "No-Library (pure JS)":

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pzgW7/

then you'll see your error again. If you include jQuery first:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/C32Gd/

things will work.

Comment: Thank you! That was driving me freaking bonkers.