# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a backbone app where I want a view to be displayed when triggered. When i click the anchor the console says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined` - I checked other issues of this kind and they say that jQuery is not loaded?? wtf? I dont get it...

My MenuView:

```
var LeftMenuView = Backbone.View.extend({

template: Handlebars.compile(Template),

events: {
'click li a.artAll': 'artAll',
},

artAll: function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var artAllRouter = new Backbone.Router();
   var route = '/artists/top100/all';
   artAllRouter.navigate(route, {trigger: true});
}
....
```

The console tells me that the error is rooted in `handlebars.js`?

My HTML template:

```
<div>
{{#each}}
<p>
    <a href="#">{{artist_name}}</a>
</p>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

and my View:

```
define(['backbone','handlebars', 'text!templates/TopAllArtists.html'],

function(Backbone,Handlebars, Template) {

var TopAllArtView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: Handlebars.compile(Template),

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },

            render: function() {
               var self = this;
               self.collection.each(function(model){
                    self.$el.append(self.template({
                        artist_name:model.get('artist_name')
                        })
                    );
               });

                return this;
            }

        });

    return TopAllArtView;
    }
 );
```

Anyone know what might be the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544290/undefined-is-not-a-function-in-backbone-js

Comment: @Anton I had no problem with jQuery before this issue...DOM tells me jQuery library is loaded

Comment: Wwhere do you define `Template`?

Comment: @Andrew I updated the code... check out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Handlebars documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/) the `each` requires a list to iterate over,

```
<ul class="people_list">
  {{#each people}}
  <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Is artist name something to iterate over?

If `model.get('artist_name')` is iterable, `['name1', 'name2', ...]` than,

```
<div>
{{#each artist_name}}
<p>
    <a href="#">{{this}}</a>
</p>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

If `model.get('artist_name')` is a string, `'Johann Sebastian Bach'` than,

```
<div>
<p>
    <a href="#">{{artist_name}}</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much! The string method was the key... How can I avoid that it renders the whole `<div>`? Like in your example I would like to add a `<h1>Artists</h1>` but for each it renders the whole block...

Comment: @SHT just update your template to not include the div and create it separately.